# Paste Visio diagram into PowerPoint table cell

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-visio

Is there a way to paste a Visio 2007 diagram into the confines of a table cell in a PowerPoint 2007 slide? I notice the diagram i paste as an **Enhanced metafile picture** is free-floating around the slide. I need it to be binded to a table cell so i can resize the tables accordingly.

As suggested below, I need the pasted image to be independently resized within the confines of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Going the image route, with the cursor in the cell, right-click Borders and Fill... Then the Fill tab, then Fill Color, then Fill Effects... from the drop-down. Then the Picture tab, then Select Picture..., then OK then OK.

Since this sets the background fill, you might have to play with sizing your image, aspect ratio, etc. But it **does** embed the image in the cell.

Caveat: this is PP 2003, but should work in 2007.

Comment: In PP 2007, it is Format Shape... in the dialog box Fill category, select Picture or texture fill; that allows pasting from clipboard. However, that stretches the image to whatever size the cell may be. Things get mighty out of proportion. give a point for the suggestion but it does not fully achieve my requirement. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just found this - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/HA010777991033.aspx

quote -

> To embed a Visio drawing in a PowerPoint slide
>
> 1. In PowerPoint, display the slide where you want to embed the drawing.
>
>    2. Choose a Blank or Title-only layout for the slide from the Slide Layout task pane.
>    3. On the Insert menu, click Object.
>    4. In the Insert Object dialog box, click Insert from file.
>    5. Browse to the Visio file you want to embed and then click OK.
>    6. To change the size of the embedded drawing on the slide, drag a corner handle.

If you are having trouble and if you do not require editing the Visio diagram later, you may be better off and save a lot of time just saving the Visio diagram as a picture and pasting it in to Powerpoint...

Not elegant, but it should work.

Comment: that is correct, i only paste as enhance metafile picture, not the full-blown diagram. anyway I wish to embed it _inside_ a table cell, not freely on the overall slide.

Comment: You should be able to do that just fine. Just create a table cell then either insert the object or picture. For a previous job, we did this with other objects just fine, there should not be any limitations.

Comment: The pasted Visio diagram or image is _independent_ of the table/cell in PowerPoint. It does not reside in the table cell.